# Why Ansible skips hosts group and does nothing

Tags: apache-spark, ansible

trying to run my Ansible and have a problem.
here is my hosts file:

```
[dse]
node1 192.168.56.10
node2 192.168.56.20
node3 192.168.56.30

[opscenter]
opscenter 192.168.56.40

[sparkmasters]
node3 192.168.56.30

[sparkworkers]
node1 192.168.56.10
node2 192.168.56.20
node3 192.168.56.30
```

Here is a part of my yml:

```
---
- hosts: [ "node1", "node2", "node3", "node4" ]
  user: vagrant
  sudo: True
  vars:
      username: spark
  tasks:
    - include: some tasks


  roles:
    - some roles


- hosts: sparkmasters
  vars:
    spark.version: 1.2
  roles:
    - spark_master

- hosts: sparkworkers
  vars:
    spark.version: 1.2
  roles:
    - spark_workers
```

I see that [ "node1", "node2", "node3", "node4" ] runs, but hosts: sparkmasters and hosts: sparkworkers are skipped with the message:

> PLAY [sparkmasters]
>   ***********************************************************  skipping: no hosts matched
>
> PLAY [sparkworkers]
>   ***********************************************************  skipping: no hosts matched
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************  node1                      : ok=21   changed=12   unreachable=0
>   failed=0
>
> ==> node1: Running provisioner: ansible...

Don't have any idea why. If i change group name to array of hosts, then it start to work...

What do I do wrong?

So I've added debug:

```
- name: Display hostvars
  debug: var=hostvars
```

And see this:

```
"hostvars": {
        "node1": {
            "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
                "10.0.2.15",
                "192.168.56.10"
            ],
```

and this huge json has much more metadata related to my host
I didn't get idea, what should I see there? I didn't find any info related to current host group info

Comment: apart from stripping out all unwanted spaces, the only other thing you might wanna do is `debug: msg="hostvars={{hostvars}}"` and look through it to see what all groups and hosts are read by ansible from inventory file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ansible+vagrant specialities: https://serverfault.com/questions/585722/ansible-not-executing-host-specific-playbook-in-vagrant-multi-machine-provisioni

So I've added gropus declaration to Vagrant file and it started to work:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "deploy.yml"
    ansible.groups = {
        "dse" => ["dsenode01","dsenode02","dsenode03"],
        "opscenter" => ["dsenode03"],
        "sparkmasters" => ["dsenode01"],
        "sparkworkers" => ["dsenode01","dsenode02","dsenode03"]
    }
  end
```