# Running Ansible against host group

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ansible-inventory

When I try running this Ansible command - `ansible testserver -m ping` it works just fine, but when I try this command - `ansible webservers -m ping` I get the following error - `ERROR! Specified hosts options do not match any hosts`.

My host file looks like this -

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

What could be the problem? Why can ansible recognize the host in question and not the host group?

I've tried changing the file to make sure ansible is reading from this file specifically, and made sure this is the case, so this is not a problem of reading configurations from another file I am not aware of.

I've also tried using the solutions specified in [Why Ansible skips hosts group and does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450889/why-ansible-skips-hosts-group-and-does-nothing) but it seems like a different problem with a different solution.

EDIT - added my anisble.cfg file, to point out I've already made all the vagrant specific configurations.

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./ansible_hosts
roles_path = ./ansible_roles
remote_user = vagrant
private_key_file = .vagrant/machine/default/virtualbox/private_key
host_key_checking = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with the vagrant and you need to ping like this:

```
ansible -i your-inventory-file webservers -m ping -u vagrant -k
```

Why your ping fail prevously:

- ansible try to connect to vagrant machine using local login user and it doesn't exist on the vagrant machine
- it also need password for the `vagrant` user which is also `vagrant`.

Hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve my problem. As I stated in my question, I made sure I'm pointing to the right inventory file (I tried adding the -i flag anyway, but the command still fails). The vagrant user is stated in the default ansible.cfg file, I'll add it to the question. Anyway this doesn't seem to be the problem since I can ssh into the server with ansible, just not when using the group name.